# How can I save the output of a color Dialog into a ini-file?

Tags: c#, .net, ini, colordialog

I'm currently coding my first app. I am saving the Userconfiguration into an ini-file. Now I need to save a color code, which the program gets from a colorDialog.

Here's the section of the code:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog colorDialog1 = new ColorDialog();
    colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string input = null;
        var userprofile_location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Appdata\Roaming\GameCentral";
        var settings = new IniFile(userprofile_location + @"\settings.ini");
        //IniFile.Write;
        settings.Write("1", input, "Color");
    }
}
```

Comment: colorDialog1.Color returns the chosen color. You can convert it to a long with Color.ToArgb and save it to your file. Or use ToString() for a more readable form, which will be harder when reading it back.. Or choose the the middle ground and go for hex: Color.ToArgb.ToString("X").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set input as below and write input to ini file. it should save hexcode.

```
string input = (colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF).ToString("X6")
```

if you want to use back hexcode, do like this:

```
string code = "FFDDAA";

Color color = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(code, 16));
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this

Comment: try and let me know whether it is working or not..however i tried and it is working..

Comment: Worked just fine. Thanks a lot!